# Offline and online execution problem with multiples queries incoming

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

I have a SQL Server service and multiple Windows Service doing some backgrounds work on same server.

One of them (I'm calling it "A") have a routine executing "single_user/offline" and "online/multi_user" to active databases to do some backup operations at midnight. The another ones executes multiple queries over that databases (I'm calling it "B").

The problem is the following:

1.- Windows Service "A" executes `SET ONLINE`.

2.- Windows Service "B" executes a random `SELECT`.

3.- Windows Service "A" tries to execute `SET MULTI_USER`. This execution is dropped because there is an active connection made from Windows Service "B".

I've tried executing `SET ONLINE` and `SET MULTI_USER` on same CommandText of the SqlCommand, but this doesn't denies the incoming query from Windows Service "B", breaking my process and keeping the database locked (because the `SINGLE_USER`).

How can I make an `ONLINE` and `MULTI_USER` commands at same time on the Windows Service "A" to make Windows Service "B" being cancelled or wait the process finished? (It's not a problem that Windows Service "B" being cancelled)

Could be `sp_dettach_db` or `sp_attach_db` useful?

Comment: Why are you offlining databases in the first place?

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, is for "copying" the physical files (mdf-ldf) to another locations. Maybe not the best way (as BACKUP command), but it must be done in that way (enterprise policies...)

Comment: Can you just shut down the SQL Server instance?

Comment: Not really, because there are some databases that must be always online, so shutting down the instance is not a solution. I'm trying with "RESTRICTED_USER" option now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, but I reanalyzed the problem I was having from the beginning, and concluded that the action "SET SINGLE_USER" was not necessary, since the process does not require actions in that mode, so finally with the action "SET OFFLINE" and "SET ONLINE" could prevent intermediate connection problems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Service A is closing it's connection after bringing the database into Single User mode. This frees up Service B to become the single user, at which point Service A can no longer change the mode until it can grab the single connection back, which it won't be able to do as long as Service B, or any other client for that matter, has it.

I can think of a couple of things you could do here:

1. Once your offline operations are complete, begin polling until Service A can become the single user again
2. Find the SPID of the connection from Service B and kill it.

See the limitations and restrictions section about single user mode at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) for more info.